# Почему в элементе "attribute" нельзя использовать свойство "ref" в XSD-файле?

Tags: xml, xsd

Почему при использовании элемента `attribute` через свойство `ref` в `XSD-файле` мы получаем ошибки в `IntellijIDEA` такого плана:

```
Attribute 'country' is not allowed to appear in element 'tariff'.
Attribute 'country' must appear on element 'tariff'.
```

Хотя, согласно [официальной документации](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#element-attribute), цитата:

> Он (элемент `attribute`) определяет простое определение типа для атрибута **либо по ссылке**, либо явно, и может предоставлять информацию по умолчанию.

В приведенном ниже исходном коде `xsd-файла` видно, что элемент `attribute` с именем `coutry` является **глобальным**. [Официальная документация](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Globals) говорит нам по этому поводу вот что:

> **Глобальные элементы и глобальные атрибуты** - создаются с помощью объявлений, которые являются дочерними элементами элемента `schema`. На глобальный элемент или глобальный атрибут можно сослаться с помощью параметра ref в одном или более объявлениях.

Вот сам **xsd-файл**, данная проблема в котором решается с помощью использования элемента `simpleType` с именем `country`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://example.by/namespace"
        xmlns:namespace="http://example.by/namespace"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <!-- root element -->
    <element name="tariffs">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="tariff" type="namespace:tariff" minOccurs="16" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

    <!-- tariff -->
    <complexType name="tariff">
        <sequence>
        <element name="information" type="string" />
        <element name="operator"    type="string" />
        <element name="prices"      type="string" />
        <element name="parameters"  type="string" />
        </sequence>

        <attribute name="coutry" type="namespace:countryType" use="required" />
    </complexType>
    
    <simpleType name="countryType">
        <restriction base="ID">
            <length value="6" />
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</schema>
```

А вот с таким `XSD-файлом` получается ошибка, которая описана выше:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://example.by/namespace"
        xmlns:namespace="http://example.by/namespace"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <!-- root element -->
    <element name="tariffs">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="tariff" type="namespace:tariff" minOccurs="16" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

    <!-- tariff -->
    <complexType name="tariff">
        <sequence>
        <element name="information" type="string" />
        <element name="operator"    type="string" />
        <element name="prices"      type="string" />
        <element name="parameters"  type="string" />
        </sequence>

        <attribute ref="namespace:coutry" use="required" />
    </complexType>
    
    <attribute name="coutry">
        <simpleType>
            <restriction base="ID">
                <length value="6" />
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
    </attribute>
    
</schema>
```

А вот так выглядит часть **XML-файла**, которая не проходит валидацию:

```xml
<operator country="BY">
    <simpleName>MTS</simpleName>
    <fullName>Mobile TeleSystems JLLC</fullName>
</operator>
```

Comment: Проблема в пространствах имён. Покажите больше схемы. Чтобы было видно, где и как задано `namespace`.

Comment: Проблема не в пространствах имён, указывай хоть так `<attribute ref="namespace:country" use="required" />`, а хоть так `<attribute ref="country" use="required" />`. Элемент `attribute` с именем `country` является **глобальным элементом**.

Comment: Проблема именно в пространстве имён. Атрибуты оказываются вне его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема из-за того, что вы не используете префикс для пространства имён схемы: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.
В итоге **элементы** без префикса имеют это пространство имён по умолчанию. Но **атрибуты** в xml не могут иметь пространства имён по умолчанию! Поэтому они оказываются вне его.

Цитата из [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) XML:

> A default namespace declaration applies to all unprefixed element names within its scope. Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear.

Если вы упорно желаете не использовать префикс, то вам придётся вынести определения типов в другую схему (в другом файле) и импортировать её в основную схему.

Comment: `Но атрибуты в xml не могут иметь пространства имён по умолчанию! ` - Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на оригинал [отсюда](https://www.w3.org/XML/Schema.html#dev), где это указано, хочу почитать подробнее.

Comment: @Jake - обновил ответ. Это нужно смотреть спецификацию XML, а не Xml Schema.